# Proving measurability of a multifunction

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathcal P (\mathbb R^m)$ be a multifunction: that is, a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to subsets of $\mathbb R^m$. It is said to be measurable if for each compact $K \subseteq \mathbb R ^m$, the set of [$x \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(x) \cap K$ is nonempty] is Lebesgue measurable.

I want to prove that $f(x)=W+ B(c(x),r(x))$ is measurable where

1. $W$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb R^m$
2. $c:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ and $r:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ measurable, $r$ being nonnegative
3. $B$ denotes the closed balls

Maybe I can fix a countable dense subset of a given compact $K$... but how should I proceed? Maybe this is a very basic problem in multifunction theory, but I am a real novice in the theory. Thanks for any hints/suggestions/solutions!

Note: this is an exercise from Francis Clark's "Calculus of Variations, Functional analysis, and Optimal control".  (I am self-studying, so this is not a homework question.)

Comment: You probably want $r$ to take values only in $[0,\infty)$, right?

Comment: Yes, since it corresponds to the radius of various balls.